# Fechamento automático de um programa

Tags: c, cmd

Como faço para que meu cmd não feche meu programa automaticamente? É .exe. Eu teria que tentar executá-lo em algum bloco de notas ou algo assim? Não sei o que devo fazer. Eu sei como executá-lo usando cm e indicando a pasta usando cmd, mas gostaria de uma forma mais objetiva e imediata, apenas dando um duplo clique no arquivo.

Seria para o arquivo .exe em C. Este é um programa que dá resultados de um determinante de uma matriz. Como se pode ver o resultado se o programa fecha em menos de 1 segundo?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(void)
{
    int m = 0;
    double **a = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    double factor = 0;
    double temp = 0;
    int count = 0;

printf("dimensao => ");
scanf("%d", &m);

a = (double **) calloc(m, sizeof(double *));
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    a[i] = (double *) calloc(m, sizeof(double));
}

printf("\n\nEntre com o conteudo da matriz\n\n");
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d ; %d] => ", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
    }
}

// mostra a matriz
printf("\nMatriz digitada:\n");
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%8.3f ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// faz a transformação em um triangulo...
for(i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
{
    if(a[i][i] == 0)
    {
        for(k = i; k < m; k++)
        {
            if(a[k][i] != 0)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    temp = a[i][j];
                    a[i][j] = a[k][j];
                    a[k][j] = temp;
                }
                k = m;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    if(a[i][i] != 0)
    {
        for(k = i + 1; k < m; k++)
        {
            factor = -1.0 * a[k][i] /  a[i][i];
            for(j = i; j < m; j++)
            {
                a[k][j] = a[k][j] + (factor * a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

temp = 1.0;
// Calcula o determinante
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    temp *= a[i][i];

printf("\nDeterminante:\n");
if(count % 2 == 0)
    printf("%8.3f \n", temp);
else
    printf("%8.3f \n", -1.0 * temp);


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é inserir `getchar()` ao final do arquivo. Em um exemplo simples de `Hello World`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

> Hello World

Outra possibilidade é inserir `system("pause");` ao final do arquivo. Entretanto, essa solução não é genérica e funciona apenas no Windows. Por isso, deve ser evitada. Com `system("pause");` o código seria:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void){
        printf("Hello World\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Para o mesmo exemplo o resultado é:

> Hello World
>
> Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Importante não esquecer do header `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Poderia ser explicado, por favor, o motivo do downvote? Dessa forma, posso editar e melhorar a resposta. Muito obrigado.